# Advanced File handling in linux and python

Tags: python, file, file-handling

I have a piece of code to make some changes in a file in Python. I wish to perform that action on multiple files of a folder. I wrote the following code to do that:

import re
import os
files = os.listdir("/home/intucell/tarfiles")
for file in files:
     fp = open (file, 'r')
     for line in fp:
        print(line.replace ('4.0.0', '5.0.0'))
f.close()

I want the code to run for multiple files in a folder called tarfiles. The names of these files have to be read from the listing of that folder. But, Linux does not read filenames containing spaces. I have about 100 files containing spaces in their names. How do I go about it?

Comment: You should look into breaking this down into two steps:
 1. Put your code into a function that take a parameter of the filename.
 2. Iterate through your list of filenames, calling this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop for this one. E.g

```
import os
item_list = next(os.walk(your_directory_path))[1]
for i in item_list:
     fp = open (str(i), 'r')
     for line in fp: print(line.replace (' 4.0.0 ', ' 5.0.0 '))
         print(re.sub(r'\b4.0.0[^.]', '5.0.0 ', line))
```

I hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the list of files `filelist` you want to work on, you can simply use:

```
import re
for filename in filelist:
    fp = open (filename, 'r') 
    for line in fp: print(line.replace (' 4.0.0 ', ' 5.0.0 '))
         print(re.sub(r'\b4.0.0[^.]', '5.0.0 ', line))`
```

Or do you need to look for the files in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

you can use os.listdir, suppose the multiple files you want to change are in folder which is stored in the path variable, then:

```
files = os.listdir(path)
for _file in files:
    fp = open (_file, 'r')
    for line in fp:
        print(line.replace (' 4.0.0 ', ' 5.0.0 '))
        print(re.sub(r'\b4.0.0[^.]', '5.0.0 ', line))
```

EDIT:
also don't forget to `import os`